# Installing Python SSL module on Windows Vista

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm running GAE SDK on a Windows Vista laptop. It keeps reminding me to install the SSL module. I've been having great difficulty on how to do that.

I've downloaded the SSL module.

I've done 'python setup.py install' in cmd, but it just says "python is not recognized as an internal..."

I've added C:\Python2.5.2 to my PATH.

Still the same message "python is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

What else should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, run `set path` and confirm that c:\Python2.5.2 is in your path?

Or, just run `c:\Python2.5.2\python setup.py install`

Also by the way I would recommend that you use 2.5.4 for app engine development, as that is the version google use in production.

The following question also has some info which might be useful: [How to install Python ssl module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261866/how-to-install-python-ssl-module-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you provide the complete path to python executable. That should work.

C:\"Python2.5.2"\python.exe setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is not specific to the ssl module, but reminded me of a problem I encountered when installing Sphinx on a Win7 machine.

You might want to call `python setup.py install` from a command prompt with administrator privileges (see [here](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/146674-windows-vista-run-command-prompt-as-administrator/) how to start a cmd prompt "as administrator").
I ran into similar problems (using easy_install) and running from an admin prompt was the solution.