# Installing SSL Module for Python (2.5.4) on Windows

Tags: python, windows-7, ssl, module, installation

since AppEngine requires to upload your apps via SSL I tried to install the module on my working laptop.

It is a x64 Win 7 System with Python 2.5.4 x86 installed.

I followed guides such as this one: [How to install Python ssl module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261866/how-to-install-python-ssl-module-on-windows)
and also all related links.

But the major problem is, that neither MinGw nor GnuWin seems to really work.

GnuWin is perfectly installed, up to date and has all dependencies it needs to build the SSL module.

But typing in

```
> "C:\Python25\python.py" setup.py install -c mingw32
```

just badly fails.
So does "-cmingw32" and "-gnuwin32".
(-cmingw32 obviously fails, because even though MinGW is fully installed MinGw is not regcognized)

"build" instead of install seems to "output" something:
MinGw complains about "ggc no such file or directory", and with GnuWin "it doesn't know how to compile C/C++ on a nt with gnuwin"

This sounds like total garbage to me, because I did everything as described in the tutorials.

**I fixed one part of my problem: gcc is now getting recognized by easy_install but AE still complains about the missing SSL module though both, easy_install and python say Pycrypto incl. SSL is successfully installed**

easy_install ssl

```
C:\Users\faits>easy_install ssl
Searching for ssl
Best match: ssl 1.15
Adding ssl 1.15 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python25\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for ssl
Finished processing dependencies for ssl
```

easy_install pycrypto

```
C:\Users\faits>easy_install ssl
Searching for ssl
Best match: ssl 1.15
Adding ssl 1.15 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python25\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for ssl
Finished processing dependencies for ssl
```

python

```
IDLE 1.2.4      
>>> import ssl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ssl\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    import _ssl2             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl2
```

python

```
>>> import pycrypto

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pycrypto
ImportError: No module named pycrypto
```

Comment: note: the compiler in mingw should be `gcc` not `ggc`.

Comment: paste the command and the exact error you get from `easy_install`.

Comment: "C:\Users\faits>easy_install ssl
Searching for ssl
Best match: ssl 1.15
Adding ssl 1.15 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python25\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for ssl
Finished processing dependencies for ssl"

Comment: make sure that directory with `_ssl2.pyd` file is in you `%PATH%`. btw, the instructions seem complicated and I'm not sure that they yield correct *64 bit* versions. Here's a useful in general page (but it doesn't have pycrypto, ssl) http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @daemonfire300: use `@J.F. Sebastian:` at the beginning of a comment if you'd like me to be notified about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-c` with the `build` command.

Compare:

`$ python setup.py install -c`

```
--compile (-c)     compile .py to .pyc [default]
```

with:

`$ python setup.py build -c`

```
--compiler (-c)    specify the compiler type
```

To find out other options , run:

`$ python setup.py build --help`

Comment: I did use build -c (e.g. --compiler=gnuwin) but, it does not know how to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I've summed up all the instructions nicely on the following link. Do check it out.
http://waqasshabbir.tumblr.com/post/18010535789/ssl-module-for-python-2-5-installation-windows-only