# "ImportError: No module named _ssl" with dev_appserver.py from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, openssl

---

## Background

> "In the Python runtime, we've added support for the Python SSL
>   Library, so you can now open secure connections to remote services
>   such as Apple's Push Notification service."

This quote is [taken from a recent post on the Google App Engine blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html).

---

## Implementation

> If you want to use native python ssl, you must enable it using the libraries configuration in your application's app.yaml file where you specify the library name "ssl" . . .

These instructions are provided for developers through the [Google App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support).

The following lines have been added to the `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

This much is in line with the advice provided through the Google App Engine documentation.

---

## Problem

I have tried running my project in three different configurations. Two are working, and one is not.

#### Working ...

After I upload my application to Google App Engine, and run my project through the live server, everything works fine.

#### Working ...

When I run my project with `manage.py runserver` and include the Google App Engine SKD in my `PYTHONPATH`, everything works fine.

#### Not Working ...

However, when I run my project with `dev_appserver.py`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named _ssl
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named _ssl
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py in load_module, line 856
Python Executable:  /home/rbose85/Code/venvs/appserver/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/rbose85/Code/product/site',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/protorpc',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/protorpc',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/protorpc',
 '/home/rbose85/Code/venvs/appserver/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/rbose85/Code/venvs/appserver/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/google_appengine',
 u'/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/django-1.4',
 u'/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/ssl-2.7',
 u'/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/webapp2-2.3',
 u'/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/webob-1.1.1',
 u'/usr/local/lib/google_appengine_1.7.7/lib/yaml-3.10']
Server time:    Wed, 24 Apr 2013 11:23:49 +0000
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can test if ssl is available at your local system by opening a python shell and typing `import ssl`. If no error appears then the problem is something else, otherwise you don't have the relevant libraries installed on your system. If you are using a Linux operating system try `sudo apt-get install openssl openssl-devel` or the relevant instructions for your operating system to install them locally. If you are using windows, these are the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261866/how-to-install-python-ssl-module-on-windows).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Very good information, but not what I need.

I agree with you, if I open the Python shell and type `import ssl` I can very quickly test if an SSL module is available to my environment.

However, I am not trying to work with SSL on my local Python. **The problem I have is working with SSL in Google App Engine**.

I am able to run my project, without issue, through Django's `manage.py runserver`.

The problem is when running my project through AppEngine's `dev_appserver.py`. When I use `dev_appserver.py` I get the above stated issue.

Comment: any solution for your problem? running into it too.

Comment: I don't have a clue, I thought it was a more system wide installation issue.

Answer (score 46):

For the current GAE version (1.8.0 at least until 1.8.3), if you want to be able to debug SSL connections in your development environment, you will need to tweak a little bit the gae sandbox:

- add "_ssl" and "_socket" keys to the dictionary _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES in /path-to-gae-sdk/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py
- Replace the socket.py file provided by google in /path-to-gae-sdk/google/appengine/dis27 from the socket.py file from your Python framework.

**IMPORTANT:** Tweaking the sandbox environment might end up with functionality working on your local machine but not in production (for example, GAE only supports outbound sockets in production). I will recommend you to restore your sandbox when you are done developing that specific part of your app.

Comment: This fix works for blocking (ssl) sockets but it won't work for non-blocking sockets. GAE (and the dev-server) wrap the select module too and the module works only with GAE socket objects. Doing a select() with a builtin socket raises exceptions. I tried to make the dev server use the builtin select module bit didn't find a way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a note for those (like me) who don't know who to find where is `path-to-gae`. Run in your Terminal: `ls -l \`which dev_appserver.py\`` this will show you the real path. Do a `cd` on the `google_appengine` dir, and then `cd google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/`.

Comment: Actually for me, from the main Google App Engine directory, you cd into google/appengine/dist27 and socket.py is right there... as jmg states in his answer.

Comment: this hack may trick the sdk but resulted with production errors (at least in my case)

Comment: I got this error when I replaced file socket.py file
File"/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 950, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _socket
Any ideas how to fix it? I had found only windows answers.

Comment: it worked! wasted a good day of head scratching trying to figure this out. thanks!

Comment: This answer stackoverflow.com/a/36272309/1464495 shows you how to do it without modifying any library files or creating any copies.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Other proposed solutions that import the sandbox module and modify it currently fail with: "ImportError: Importing the devappserver sandbox module (google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python.runtime.sandbox) from user application code is not permitted. Please remove this import."

Answer (score 16):

The solution by [jmg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16937668) works, but instead of changing the sdk files, you could monkey patch the relevant modules.

Just put something like this on the beginning of your project setup.

```
# Just taking flask as an example
app = Flask('myapp')

if environment == 'DEV':
    import sys

    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']

    from lib import copy_of_stdlib_socket.py as patched_socket

    sys.modules['socket'] = patched_socket
    socket = patched_socket
```

Comment: +1 for code only solution and no need to muster with the appengine files.

Comment: If you get here and use this solution and you then get an issue about non-blocking sockets (and using `select`). Adding these two lines to the fix, right below `import sys` will disable non-blocking sockets entirely: `import select` and then `del sys.modules['select'].select`.

Comment: `from lib import copy_of_stdlib_socket.py as patched_socket`
What's this line about? PyCharm says "module not found."

Comment: Agreed, improve your answer please.

Comment: For those wondering about `copy_of_stdlib_socket.py`, the idea is to literally copy the Python core `socket.py` file to a new file in your project's directory tree, with a name like `copy_of_stdlib_socket.py`, then import that. There's something overriding the default socket module, and we want to override it back.

Comment: You can accomplish this without even having to copy `socket.py` to a new file, per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36272309/1464495.

Answer (score 6):

I had to use a slightly different approach to get this working in CircleCI (unsure what peculiarity about their venv config caused this):

**`appengine_config.py`**

```
import os

if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    import imp
    import os.path
    import inspect
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox

    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']
    # Use the system socket.

    real_os_src_path = os.path.realpath(inspect.getsourcefile(os))
    psocket = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(real_os_src_path), 'socket.py')
    imp.load_source('socket', psocket)
```

Comment: This answer seems like the safest route to go and should be marked up. I'll add that it should be placed in a file called `appengine_config.py` in your base app directory so that it gets loaded on startup.

Comment: line 737, in HTTPConnection
I got    timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, source_address=None):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'

Comment: Looks a perfect solution but in my case I am using virtualenv and it's not able to find socket.py on manually downloading and placing socket.py it's giving an error saying **[Errno 22] Invalid argument**.

Comment: @vinitpayal unfortunately GAE doesn't work well with venv.  vendoring is the best way to go - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: @SpainTrain Thanks for your reply after investing a lot of time I was able to make this work on venv. I think the one which worked was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822937/app-engine-socket-invalid-argument/36272309#36272309

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem because I wasn't vendoring `ssl` in my app.yaml file.  I know the OP did that, but for those landing here for the OP's error, it's worth making sure lines like the following are in your app.yaml file:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Comment: They really should have mentioned this in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env

Comment: seriously.  GAE started out as their flagship PaaS and in this transition to 3.7, they've been treating it as a side project (ie nearly no local dev tools for 3.7, not updating 2.7 documentation when they make changes, not migrating built-in libraries (ie NDB) to 3.7, etc).  Here's hoping the rest of 2019 shows improvement here as Python 2.7 gets sunset.

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled upon this thread trying to work with Apples Push notification service and appengine... I was able to get this working without any monkey patching, by adding the SSL library in my app.yaml, as recommended in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support#specifying_the_ssl_library), hope that helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

I added the code to appengine_config.py as listed by Spain Train, but had to also add the following code as well to get this to work:

```
phttplib = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(real_os_src_path), 'httplib.py')
imp.load_source('httplib', phttplib)
```