# Send iOS Push Notifications from Google App Engine python

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine

I have been looking everywhere for example code on how to do this from a python written server over GAE - but with no luck.

Can someone please help me with the function to do this? (It should be pretty straight forward I believe).

Comment: Have you looked at any of the python APNS libraries and tried using them?

Comment: Well, I know GAE has a problem with sockets, and they require opening it. I was wondering if someone has any experience and can simply direct me to what is best to use.

Comment: There used to a restriction on opening outbound sockets from the GAE sandbox which meant that you could only send push notifications through services like urban airship or parse.  Outbound sockets are now a "preview" feature - https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/ so it may not stay forever, but it is available

Answer (score 1):

I use this library, and it works well in my app.
https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs

enable ssl in app.yaml

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

code is like below, token_hex == a push notification token sent from a device. And you have to some variables.

```
from apns import APNs, Payload
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=use_sandbox, 
        cert_file=path/to/cert.pem',
        key_file=path/to/key-noenc.pem')
payload = Payload(alert='hello', sound="default", badge=1,custom={})
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
for (token_hex, fail_time) in apns.feedback_server.items():
    logging.info(token_hex) 
    logging.info(fail_time)
```

Comment: I get this error when using this lib: 
apns.py", line 155, in _connect
    self._ssl = wrap_socket(self._socket, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers)
TypeError: must be _socket.socket, not socket

Comment: you have to enable ssl library in app.yaml

Comment: @LiorZ you also have to apply this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192916/importerror-no-module-named-ssl-with-dev-appserver-py-from-google-app-engine/16937668#16937668

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may consider this forked version of PyAPNS that has enhanced message support.
https://github.com/jimhorng/PyAPNs 
which means it will catch error response for failure messages and resent the message which are discarded by APNS while sending between failure messages and receiving error response.

Solution:

- Non-blocking ssl socket connection to send notification without waiting for response.
- A separate thread for constantly checking error-response from read connection.
- A sent notification buffer used for re-sending notification that were sent after failed notification, or arbitrary connection close by apns.
  (Reference to non-blocking apns pull request by minorblend, enhanced message by hagino3000)

Result:

- Send notification at throughput of 1000/secs
- In worse case of when 1st notification sent failed, error-response respond after 1 secs and 999 notification sent are discarded by APNS at the mean time, all discarded 999 notifications will be resent without loosing any of them. With the same logic, if notification resent failed, it will resent rest of resent notification after the failed one.