# Workaround for dev_appserver.py inability to make SSL requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, braintree, dev-appserver

Ran into this problem trying to call `braintree.ClientToken.generate()` from a Google App Engine app, running Flask on `dev_appserver.py`. `dev_appserver.py` can't currently make outgoing SSL connections. Making the above braintree call yields

`ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`

The call works on in a real GAE environment. It's used in one of my views, so it breaks my whole website flow with the above 500 error when it fails. How can I work around this so that I can continue developing in my local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

For help with the Braintree Python library on GAE, see [this example on my GitHub](https://github.com/agfor/braintree-python-appengine). To answer your question, you can [force the dev server to use the real Python socket library](https://github.com/agfor/braintree-python-appengine/blob/master/main.py#L18-L30), so SSL connections work:

```
try:
    # This is needed to make local development work with SSL.
    # This must be done *before* you import the Braintree Python library.
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066819/500584
    # and https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9246 for more information.
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']

    import sys
    # this is socket.py copied from a standard python install
    import stdlib_socket
    sys.modules['socket'] = stdlib_socket
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: This is an answer to a different question (I think). If I understand correctly, this enables incoming SSL connections to dev_appserver.py, not outgoing ones. The problem I was encountering is that dev_appserver can't make outgoing SSL connections. I was pretty frustrated when all I could find at all related to my problem was this answer, which of course I tried to no avail whatsoever, strewn all over the internet.

Comment: @brandones You're mistaken. This fix is specifically to enable outgoing SSL connections.

Comment: Didn't work for me. There are a few variants of this fix that I tried as well. I just kept getting the same error -- `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`

Comment: @brandones If you post a minimal example of code with the fix from my answer that still has the problem for you, I'll be glad to take a look tomorrow and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Turns out I was calling `import braintree` above this code, so it wasn't using the provided socket module. `import braintree` needs to come *after* this code. I think that would be a good thing to specify, since it's certainly not obvious.

Comment: As an aside, silently swallowing ImportErrors is a classic Bad Idea. This bit me in the ass when I had a path problem with `stdlib_socket`. For my application, I was able to remove the `try/except` entirely and make the code conditional on the environment. Since that's not always an option I hugely recommend replacing `except ImportError: pass` with `except ImportError, e: print e`.

Comment: Now I'm getting `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(22, 'Invalid argument'))` on calls to `braintree.ClientToken.generate()`. Pretty sure that means I'm past this issue though. I'll open a new question, @agf ?

Comment: @brandones Yep, that would do it. I'll make the fact that this is ordering dependent more clear. When you post your new question, link it here and please include a minimal example so I can try to reproduce.

Comment: I pushed an update to my example with the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some variable global to your app that corresponds with when you're running in `dev_appserver.py`, you can create a mock of the failing method conditioned on that variable.

In my case, that variable is called `env_conf.FLASK_CONF`. I used the following code to mock the braintree generate call.

```
# Imports
import braintree
import env_conf
from flask import render_template

# Mock Braintree in DEV environment
if env_conf.FLASK_CONF == 'DEV':
    from functools import partial
    def mock_generate(self):
        return 'foobarbaz123'
    braintree.ClientToken.generate = partial(mock_generate, braintree.ClientToken())

# Add payment handler
def add_payment():
    token = braintree.ClientToken.generate()
    return render_template('add-payment.html',
                           braintree_client_token=token)
```

The idea generically is:

```
import problem_function
if DEV_ENVIRONMENT:
    def mock_problem_fcn():
        return 'expected response'
    problem_function = mock_problem_function

problem_function()
```