# GAE and urllib2.py errors with and without SSL and Sockets - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, urllib2, httplib, google-app-engine-python

I have a service on GAE which retrieves data from different sources online. Each provider has a different authentication protocol and so far I've been able to connect to all of them with a mix of standard urllib2 calls or oauth mechanisms.

Recently one of them switched to the json-rpc with client certificates authentication. In order to make it work I had to enable billing on GAE, import the ssl module, force httplib to use sockets and patch some modules to make it work on the dev environment ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192916/importerror-no-module-named-ssl-with-dev-appserver-py-from-google-app-engine))

I got that working in the end.

**However, as soon as I force httplib to use sockets...**

```
env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

**...all the other scripts relying on very simple urllib2 calls like this one...**

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = opener.open(request)
```

**...start to fail!!!**

Here is the traceback:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1166, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. I found some threads here on stackoverflow that mention a bug in Python 2.7.9 that should be fixed in 2.7.10 (which I'm using).

Anyone came across a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest version of the GAE SDK.  Some previous versions were incompatible with python >=2.7.9 (see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11536) for more information).

Comment: Ben, thanks for the input. It's the first thing I checked... I'm running v1.9.24 which is the latest available.

Comment: Actually, I've just discovered that 1.9.30 is available. Not sure why the auto-updater in engine launcher didn't prompt anything...