# Is there a way to send push notifications to a web browser from Google appengine standard?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to add chat to a web application I've been working on.

I've searched the Google documentation, but cannot find a way to send push notifications from a server to a web application running on Google's appengine standard environment.

The latest release notes indicate that websockets are not supported, and XMPP is not available either. For this project, there is no budget available for a third party solution, and I'd rather cut the code myself anyway.

What APIs are available to me? Surely there must be something or some way of building this sort of functionality?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a few different things here.

To send a push notification to a browser, this answer has you covered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33976929/4458510

As for doing this on GAE, all you really need is outbound https right? It isn't the most straight forward to set up, but this is what I needed to do to get outbound https working in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550041/4458510

I've never bothered with browser push notications, but do send APNS & GCM push notifications to our mobile app from GAE Standard with the linked code.