# Google App Engine / Twilio SSLError: Max retries exceeded

Tags: google-app-engine, twilio

Good day, everyone. I'm just trying to run the Twilio quickstart script (from this webpage: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python) on my Google App Engine app.

It runs perfectly as-is on my local machine, and when I deploy it (the exact same script) to my Google App Engine app so I can send SMS's on-demand using a GET request to my app, I get the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcaf61e51a95ba4454501293b8908aefd/Messages.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))
```

I've tried adding SSL to my GAE app.yaml with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by manually specifying SSL version "2.7.11" in my app.yaml instead of using "latest."

Answer (score 0):

Getting outbound HTTPS working in app engine requires some coercing. Have you tried everything in my answer to this questions?

[HTTPS get using "requests" module in Google App Engine fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548112/https-get-using-requests-module-in-google-app-engine-fails/51550041#51550041)