# Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, request, python-requests

I am trying to fill google form using python script. I am getting error because of ssl module.

Here is code that I wrote

```
    def send_attendance(url, data):
        """It takes google form url which is to be submitted and also data which is a list of data to be submitted in the form iteratively."""
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'
        header={'User-Agent' : user_agent}
        for d in data:
            try:
                requests.get(url,data=d,headers=header),
                print("Form Submitted.")
                time.sleep(5)
            except Exception as err:
                print("Error occured {}".format(err))
```

Error occured HTTPSConnectionPool(host='docs.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /forms/d/1JxbxYl7ZnWTEKtYqVMQJOi_6_cZvTYrDbGsPeNNnGSY/formResponse (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261866/how-to-install-python-ssl-module-on-windows